# How to open up macro enabled excel in vba

Tags: excel, vba

The idea is I'm able to open each xls in my folder, scan through the worksheets and copy & paste in my open worksheet. For some odd reason, my sub says it's can't find my folder and keeps asking if it's deleted. Can anyone help me troubleshoot

```
Option Explicit
Option Base 1

Sub OpenWorkbooks()
Dim w As Worksheet, i As Integer, j As Integer
Dim Folder As String, FileName As String
Dim aWB As Workbook, tWB As Workbook
Dim nr As Integer, nc As Integer
Dim S() As Integer, mx As Integer
Dim c As Variant
Dim example As Range
Set example = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A1")
nr = 9
nc = 5
ReDim S(nr, nc)
Folder = "C:\Users\Dhruv\Desktop\macro"
FileName = Dir(Folder & "\*.xlsm")
Do
    Workbooks.Open Folder & "\" & FileName
    Set aWB = ActiveWorkbook
    For Each w In Worksheets
        For i = 1 To nr
            For j = 1 To nc
                 If w.Range("A1:D6").Cells(i, j) = "Time" Then
                    c = c + 1
                    example.Offset(i + c, j) = c
                 End If
            Next j
        Next i
    Next
    aWB.Close SaveChanges:=False
    FileName = Dir
Loop Until FileName = " "
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you sure there’s at least one matching file in the folder?

Comment: What is the exact error? Also what is an example filename from folder `C:\Users\Dhruv\Desktop\macro\ ` ?

Comment: Your loop should be `Do While FileName <> ""  ...  Loop` otherwise it will run at least once even if there are no matching files